# Compiled batch file run fullscreen

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batchfiles which basicly just "echo"s text into the cmd window. I compiled it to an exe but want it to be in full screen without borders and without taskbar.(Windows 7)

It should work without having to create a shortcut or any other settings like this.

It can be in the Batch code or the exe but it should start in fullscreen when - for example - I download and execute it on another computer without me having to set any settings.

Is that even possible in Batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean running cmd.exe in fullscreen in Windows 7, it's basically impossible. Lots of people were complaining about it.

There are plenty "fake" fullscreen command lines. 
You can use [this one](http://blog.amolbhave.in/computers/full-screen-command-prompt-in-vista-and-windows-7/) and run the batch there.

Comment: Does the User also have to have this installed or can I just add it to my bat file?

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible to add such a command to a bat file without the user having something like this installed, right?

Comment: If you want a computer to display the commandline in fullscreen, you will have to get that fake fullscreen program, too.
The program only displays, and for running batches, try a batch who starts this program with your batch. Tricky situation.

Comment: Well i could add like the Source Code of this Fullscreen programm to it, that should work, shouldn't it? It's probably not batch... so well still thank you.

Comment: Theoretically, there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: But on it's website it states that i need .net Framework, so I don't think it's batch and I would probably need the change the language to like C# or VB?

Comment: .NET Framework is only needed to run the app. Vista started on .NET 2.0. That means every computer with Vista and newer have already .NET included. Don't worry, (almost) every computer with Windows has .NET 2.0 and higher, so the program will run. Just use start the program and run your batch.